# How can I get latitude and longitude from FIPS codes?

Tags: geocoding, census, reverse-geocoding

I have full FIPS codes down to the block, looking for a way to convert the FIPS codes into centroid latitude/longitude for each block. Basically this but backwards (and I'd like blocks, not just tracks): [API to reverse geocode latitude, longitude to census tract?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21533/api-to-reverse-geocode-latitude-longitude-to-census-tract)

Comment: could you download the census block dataset, join, then export the coordinates of the block geometries?

Comment: Where can I get the coordinates of the geometries?

Comment: What software do you have access to?

Comment: https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2016&layergroup=Blocks+%282010%29

Comment: Not much software available for me...currently playing around with ArcGIS explorer, got that census.gov file, which seems to have exactly what I need... but I need a way to export the attribute table as an excel file, stata file, .csv, or .txt. Attribute table won't open because there are too many elements. Any advice?

Comment: QGIS will get you what you need